# Is there a way to change Window style to none using override of CreateParams?

Tags: c#, .net, styles, window, createparams

I am trying to create application with window style set to "None". As far as I know, I can change style and extended style using override of CreateParams:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                //cp.Style |= ???
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x80;  // Turn on WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
                return cp;
            }
        }
```

I use ExStyle as 0x80, in order application not to show in taskbar or Task Manager. What also should I use in order to change window style to None? I just cannot understand what style to use according to [List of Styles](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/Window%20styles.html).

Comment: What is your intention?  "None" equates to `WS_OVERLAPPED` (0x00000000L) which is the default for your typical app.  Did you want it to be invisible? No SysMenu? No frame?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx.  Also to hide from task bar it is not necessary to resort to changing CreateParams

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My intention is removing minimizing and restoring animation, I've read some resources, where it was pointed, that in order to completely eliminate these animations, you just need to set Window style as none. I am creating Form application, and I guess, that FormBorder style is not the same as WindowStyle, because with FormBorder style set to None I still have these animations. Thanks again for your reply!

Comment: You are quite welcome.  I don't know much about it but maybe the _Desktop Window Manger_ might be useful here.  Try http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/497415-Way-to-detect-DWM-openclose-window-animations and for greater detail https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540(v=vs.85).aspx